GRU vs MLP tensorflow network for tabular data in inverse scattering problems
I am working with the following problem: My X data are far-field measurements in a surface (90k rows with 20 features) where the features are e.g. column 1 = measurement at 0 degrees, column 2 = measurement at 10 degrees, etc. The X features are in general correlated. Each row corresponds to a different sample. My target y values are 90k rows and 6 columns, which are positions in polar coordinates of the sources producing the surface data. My problem is a multioutput regression problem. My data are stored in .csv and loaded in the NN models.
I successfully used MLP to solve it like e.g :
 
model = Sequential([   
Dense(500, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(2e-4)),    
Dense(500, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(2e-4)), 
Dropout(0.2, seed=42), 
Dense(500, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(2e-4)),    Dropout(0.2, seed=42), 
Dense(500, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(2e-4)), 
Dropout(0.2, seed=42), 
Dense(500, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(2e-4)), 
Dense(6, activation = None)   
])

The results are decent.
Nevertheless, I found in the bibliography that GRU are used in this type of problems, e.g. https://www.mdpi.com/2218-1997/9/3/148 or LSTM in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2020.109594
I guess because there is a spatial sequential "nature" in the X features, since they are measurements at a specific sequence in space.
I tried to implement a GRU for my problem as:
time_steps = X_train.shape[1]  # Number of angular positions 
features = 1  # Each feature corresponds to one angular position measurement  
batch_size = 32     
model = Sequential([  
GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, time_steps, features),      stateful=True), 
Dropout(0.1), 
GRU(units=256, return_sequences=False, stateful=True), 
Dense(6)  # 6 output units for 6 target variables     
 ])

My results are questionable.
Does it make more sense to use GRU instead of MLP in this type of problems?
Also, is it correct to use
 
time_steps = X_train.shape[1]  # Number of angular positions
features = 1  # Each feature corresponds to one angular position measurement   

or should I do:
time_steps = 1     
features = X_train.shape[1]"

?
If I understand correctly, the later is used when the "sequential" behavior lies in the rows of the training sample (e.g. in timeseries problems).
I would really appreciate and ideas in this.
Best,
p.s. I tried both MLP and GRU models, and am trying to figure out which fits the physics of the problem more appropriately.
